# Как вызвать метод веб-сервиса с параметрами?

Tags: c#, asp.net, веб-служба

Подскажите пример как на C# вызвать метод веб-сервиса (`asp.net`) с параметрами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Первая ссылка](http://sarangasl.blogspot.ru/2010/09/create-simple-web-service-in-visual.html) в гугле по запросу "asp.net web service example"